# Capture mouseover in d3 on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, mouseover

Is there a way to combine OpenStreetmap leaflet.js map with d3.js objects in such a way to capture "mouseover" tooltips on d3 objects? In the following example where I would like to create a console "ook" event when the mouse passes over the blue circle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>d3.js with leaflet.js</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js">
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 1350px; height: 662px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var radius = 8;
var map = L.map('map').setView([53.69, -1.14], 14);
mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);
/* Initialize the SVG layer */
L.svg().addTo(map);
/* We simply pick up the SVG from the map object */
var svg = d3.select("#map").select("svg")
  , g = svg.append("g");
var data = [{
    "node": "interesting",
    "x": 641,
    "y": 295
}]
var feature = g.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("svg:circle").style("fill", "steelblue").attr("r", 20).attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}).on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log("ook" + d.node);
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In debug it appears that mouse events are captured in the leaflet code and not passed over to d3. Help or suggestions gratefully received

Comment: D3 is a great package when data is changing. Are you using d3 to just add svg svg elements to Leaflet? What is the format/size of the data you expect to use?

Comment: The plan (such as it is) is to use d3 transitions to provide tooltips over a leaflet map on multiple sets of points. Clearly the the dataset here is small but the working systems using d3 and leaflet without tooltips has over 500k points stored in json and csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the circle, include:

> .attr("pointer-events","visible")